# getting a factor x10 by parsing a string to double

Tags: parsing

I want that the number entered by console to be treated as double ty by my programm:

I can't understand why the following code gives me the result with a factor x10, if for example I enter 13.5 by keyboard, the Console.WriteLine ("m") gives me a 135 ...

```
Console.WriteLine("Escriba la longitud:");
        string l = Console.ReadLine();
        double m = double.Parse(l);
       
Console.WriteLine(m);
```

any explanation?

Many thanks!!

Comment: I suppose that in your current locale, `.` is a thousands separate and `,` is the decimal indicator. C# is locale-aware but tolerant about where the thousands separators go.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Exactly! I discovered the , and . is making this problem.